# Remove data-iconshadow="false" from JQM Collapsible title

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to do this for a while with CSS and also data attributes but it is driving me up the wall. It's easy to remove data-iconshadow from buttons, but from collapsibles, not so.

In the Developer Console I can see JQM is applying "data-iconshadow='true'" even after I told it not to using this code (in several places):

```
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-iconshadow="false">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="f" data-collapsed-icon="baby" class="ui-icon-nodisc" data-iconshadow="false" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
        <h2 data-iconshadow="false">0-12 Months</h2>
        **insert content here**
        </div>
  </div>
```

Yet it still generates this code:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-f" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="baby" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="f"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">0-12 Months<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-arrow-u">&nbsp;</span></span></a>
```

Yeah it is still writing the data-iconshadow to be true. And I'm not even sure how to target injected attributes with CSS so I am not having much luck with that either. If someone could shed some light on the subject, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/2NCjb/

#### HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="f" data-collapsed-icon="baby" class="ui-icon-nodisc" data-iconshadow="false" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u" id="custom-collapsible">
        <h2 data-iconshadow="false">0-12 Months</h2>
        **insert content here**
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#custom-collapsible h2 .ui-btn:after {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```